# The Diophantine Equation $m(n-2016)=n^{2016}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

> How many natural numbers, $n$, are there such that $$\frac{n^{2016}}{n-2016}$$ is a natural number?

HINT.-There are lots of solutions

HINT.-$\frac{n}{n-2016}=m \iff \frac{2016}{n-2016}=m-1$ and if, for example, $x=a^r\cdot b^s$ then the factors of $x$ are all the $a^i\cdot b^j$ with $0\le i\le r$ and $0\le j\le s$

Comment: You have been quite active here for a significant time, so you should know to add more context to the question. What have you tried?

Comment: I meant the first part as a compliment. You have been a member of the MSE community for nine months and have asked good questions and given good answers. But despite this, useful context is missing from this question. You give a hint: does that mean you know the answer and this is a challenge, or were you given this as an assignment? And so on. I am sure, with your demonstrated skills, that you could improve the question. And yes, I did vote to close the question, but I will readily remove that vote if you add context.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'll give another hint (believe me, however,I swear I am not interested in reputation points, I am just as the nickname of a member of MSE, a Mathlover)

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Dear friend, my English is so  weak  to misundertand your courtesy. Believe me, I read good enough and I write badly with the help of Google, but I cannot talk, I can't converse so I don't speak English,

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I wanted to delete this question but I have been noticed that is bad to delete answered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions (I think all of them):

$2017$

$2^k + 2016$ for $1\leq k\leq 10080$.

$a^k + 2016$ for $1\leq k\leq 4032$ and $a\in \{3,6,12\}$

$b^k + 2016$ for $1\leq k\leq 2016$ and $b\mid 2016$ and $b\not\in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$

You can show that this solutions won't work for $k$ greater than the upper limits I've set. Also if a prime $p$ divides $n - 2016$ but doesn't divide $2016$ then it won't divide $n^{2016}$ (since it doesn't divide $n$). So from $2016 = 2^53^27^1$ we know that any solution $n$ must be of the form $2^r3^s7^t + 2016$.

Comment: See, please, dear friend, the second hint I have added to the question. A part of you reasonning can be change by $E>0$ where $E$ is the given expression.

Comment: Do you mean $n^{2016}/(n-2016) > 0$. If so, just disregard the last line.

Comment: By definition because the quotient must be a natural number.

Answer (score 2):

Show, in general, that $\gcd\left(x-k,x^m\right)=\gcd\left(x-k,k^m\right)$ for all integers $x,k,m$ with $m \geq 0$.  Therefore, for positive integers $k$ and $m$, the number of integers $n$ such that
$$\dfrac{n^m}{n-k}\in\mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$$
is precisely the number of positive divisors of $k^m$.